# Opacity not fading back with a hidden menu on Safari and chrome browser?

Tags: jquery, css, safari, opacity

please see this example http://intelligen.info/index.html

The menu at the top of this page has opacity set at 0 and when you hover at is change to 1. This works fine in firefox but if you view it on safari and chrome some of the menu sticks and doesn't fade out when the hovering has stopped. Anyone know how to prevent this sticking on safari and chrome?

```
$('#nav, #logo').hover(function() {
$('#nav').fadeTo(1,1);
},function() {
$('#nav').fadeTo(1,0);
});
$('#lfw-link, #lfw').hover(function() {
$('#nav, #lfw').fadeTo(1,1);
},function() {
$('#nav, #lfw').fadeTo(1,0);
});
$('#clients-link, #clients').hover(function() {
$('#nav, #clients').fadeTo(1,1);
},function() {
$('#nav, #clients').fadeTo(1,0);
});
$('#personal-link, #personal').hover(function() {
$('#nav, #personal').fadeTo(1,1);
},function() {
$('#nav, #personal').fadeTo(1,0);
});
$('#video-link, #videos').hover(function() {
$('#nav, #videos').fadeTo(1,1);
},function() {
$('#nav, #videos').fadeTo(1,0);
});
```

Comment: it flickers in Chrome, too.

Comment: Please post some sample code. A link to a live website is useless for posterity, since you're going to fix it when you get the answer.